# Is there a way to pass slicing commands of Slic3r as an external application using C++ in an automated way

Tags: c++, windows, slice

After researching I was able to find a way to access/open another software using c++ code and found a more flexible and scriptable slicing software "Slic3r"

It has particular commands that can be used for slicing an object, you can find the command manual [here](https://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/command-line)

Some command examples are,

> slic3r --gcode --merge model1.stl model2.stl
>
> slic3r --cut 20 cube.stl

I will be mentioning these commands as list or option for the user in a gui format and after the user has selected all that it would pass these commands to the 3d slicer.

Currently I am trying to write a c++ code on Visual Studio to pass slicing commands to a 3D slicer and get the infill-output, without manually performing the slicing.

I tried using the following code but I am unable to declare or define the library for the slic3r since the website doesn't really have any documentation on their website,
I am able to open the slicer but the second command line to execute something in the slicer doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   system ("C:/Users/msharma/Desktop/Slic3r-1.3.0.64bit/Slic3r- 
   console.exe");
   system("slic3r --help-options");
   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Error I am receiving now, even though i shouldn't need to declare any library for using the system call in the console application.

```
'slic3r' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: It does call the program, but the output is lost. You need [`_popen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) to retrieve the output of the system call.

Comment: It gives out an error saying ""argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"C/C++(167)""

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code that you are compiling? All the arguments passed to `std::system` calls are `const char*`. Please provide [mcve] (including complete error message).

Comment: I was able to run the system call files without _popen but the library is not getting included

Comment: ***'slic3r' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.*** Means the folder that the `slic3r` program is in is not one of the folders listed in your system `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You could solve the ***not recognized as an internal ...*** error also by using the full path to the executable instead of just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the application by running it as "slic3r.**exe**" and then run the commands.

Best way to understand it to write it in the same way someone would write a command in cmd to run an application.